# How to find the bounds of known text in an image?

Tags: c#, .net, ocr

I have a screenshot of a window. I would like to find the bounds of a string that is in the image. For example, I would like to get the bounds of the text "label2" in the following image:

[image]

I realize that this probably requires re-scaling the image and using OCR. Unfortunately, information I could find about OCR revolves around *reading* the text, not *finding* it. What can I use in .NET to accomplish this (and how)?

Comment: Do you have access to that window? It sounds like you're asking for a window outside your solution. Also, are you taking the screenshot, or are you processing a screenshot taken at a different time/place?

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger the window belongs to an application that runs on the same computer as mine does. I can't use the `GetWindowText` WinAPI because the text does not belong to a control as its text, it is just drawn there by other means. I'm taking the screenshot in my application.

Comment: Is the text you're after always the same or does it fluctuate (different letters/font or same letters/font).

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger I can't make assumptions about the font, but for one string in the same application it stays the same. So I can assume that "label2" in the same application always looks the same. "label1" might look different.

Comment: You might want to look into using [Tesseract](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tesseract/).  Like most OCR engines it will give you bounding boxes for the characters that it reads.  It would be up to you to determine which ones are what you are looking for which you haven't really made clear here.

Comment: @juharr Tesseract is definitely on my radar, but I couldn't find information about how to get the bounding boxes and how to use it from .NET (I found old wrappers with bad documentation)

Comment: That's where I was going... IDK if spy++ allows for that functionality.

Comment: There's also this I used for something similar. It's been a while and I don't recall the specific functionality but maybe it will help... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9741/Screen-Captures-Window-Captures-and-Window-Icon-Ca

Comment: Id' really appreciate it if you'd share your answer when/if you find one. Wish I had more to help with. Good luck!!

Comment: May be you can  try Sikulix ( http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) , i think it has c# wrapper